# How to list all files in a directory dynamicaly with python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to python and tkinter and I try to create a tool witch loops every 5 seconds over a directory to list all the files.

In my code the filenames in the list appears only after I interupt the loop.

My goal is to start a loop by clicking on a button to start the endless loop to list the files and a stop button to stop the loop.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import time
import os

global dateiListe

def browse_button():
    global pfad
    global dateiname
    dateiname = filedialog.askdirectory()
    pfad.set(dateiname)
    if len(dateiname) > 0:
        print( len(dateiname) )
        btn_schleifeStart['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    else:
        print( len(dateiname) )
        btn_schleifeStart['state'] = tk.DISABLED

def start_schleife():
    btn_ordnerWählen['state'] = tk.DISABLED
    btn_schleifeStart['state'] = tk.DISABLED
    while True:
        dateiListe = []
        for datei in os.listdir(dateiname):
            if datei.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
                listBox.insert(1, datei)
                listBox.insert(2, datei)
                print(datei)
        time.sleep(5)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")
pfad = tk.StringVar()

btn_ordnerWählen = tk.Button(text="Ordner wählen", command=browse_button)
btn_schleifeStart = tk.Button(text="Start", command=start_schleife,state=tk.DISABLED)
txt_pfad = tk.Label(master=root,textvariable=pfad, fg="blue")
listBox = tk.Listbox(root)

btn_ordnerWählen.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="sw")
txt_pfad.grid(row=1, column=0)
btn_schleifeStart.grid(row=3, column=0)
listBox.grid(row=4, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the infinite loop, which blocks `mainloop()` and causes the program to freeze, and use a `.after()` call.

The `.after` has two main attributes, the delay and the function, so `root.after(time, function)` will return a scheduled job.

This job can be stored as a global variable in the style used and canceled with a stop function.

For the sake of not constantly adjusting the `state` of the buttons I added a separate run function.

Example:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import time
import os

global dateiListe

def browse_button():
    global pfad
    global dateiname
    dateiname = filedialog.askdirectory()
    pfad.set(dateiname)
    if len(dateiname) > 0:
        print( len(dateiname) )
        btn_schleifeStart['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    else:
        print( len(dateiname) )
        btn_schleifeStart['state'] = tk.DISABLED

def start_schleife():
    btn_ordnerWählen['state'] = tk.DISABLED
    btn_schleifeStart['state'] = tk.DISABLED
    btn_schleifeStop['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    run_schleife() # Calls run function

def run_schleife():
    global job # Make job variable global
    dateiListe = []
    for datei in os.listdir(dateiname):
        if datei.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
            listBox.insert(1, datei)
            listBox.insert(2, datei)
            print(datei)

    job = root.after(5000, run_schleife) # schedules a job to run the function again after 5000ms.

def stop_schleife():
    # Added a function to stop
    root.after_cancel(job) # cancels the scheduled job.
    btn_ordnerWählen['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    btn_schleifeStart['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    btn_schleifeStop['state'] = tk.DISABLED

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")
pfad = tk.StringVar()

btn_ordnerWählen = tk.Button(text="Ordner wählen", command=browse_button)
btn_schleifeStart = tk.Button(text="Start", command=start_schleife,state=tk.DISABLED)
btn_schleifeStop = tk.Button(text="Stop", command=stop_schleife,state=tk.DISABLED) # Added stop button
txt_pfad = tk.Label(master=root,textvariable=pfad, fg="blue")
listBox = tk.Listbox(root)

btn_ordnerWählen.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="sw")
txt_pfad.grid(row=1, column=0)
btn_schleifeStart.grid(row=3, column=0)
btn_schleifeStop.grid(row=4, column=0) # Grid stop button
listBox.grid(row=5, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

## If you were interested in using threading

Here is how I would approach it:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import time
import os
import threading # import threading

global dateiListe

def browse_button():
    global pfad
    global dateiname
    dateiname = filedialog.askdirectory()
    pfad.set(dateiname)
    if len(dateiname) > 0:
        print( len(dateiname) )
        btn_schleifeStart['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    else:
        print( len(dateiname) )
        btn_schleifeStart['state'] = tk.DISABLED

def start_schleife():
    global job # Declare global variable to hold Thread
    btn_ordnerWählen['state'] = tk.DISABLED
    btn_schleifeStart['state'] = tk.DISABLED
    btn_schleifeStop['state'] = tk.NORMAL

    job = threading.Thread(target = run_schleife) # Create thread object
    job.run_thread = True # Sets the "run_thread" attribute to True
    job.start() # Start Thread

def run_schleife():
    thread = threading.current_thread()
    while True:
        dateiListe = []
        for datei in os.listdir(dateiname):
            if datei.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
                listBox.insert(1, datei)
                listBox.insert(2, datei)
                print(datei)
        for x in range(50): # 5 second wait, 50 x 0.1 seconds = 5 seconds
            if not getattr(thread, "run_thread"): # Checks "run_thread" attribute
                print("run_schleife thread stopped")
                return
            time.sleep(0.1)

def stop_schleife():
    # Added a function to stop
    job.run_thread = False # Sets the thread's "run_thread" attribute to False
    btn_ordnerWählen['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    btn_schleifeStart['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    btn_schleifeStop['state'] = tk.DISABLED

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")
pfad = tk.StringVar()

btn_ordnerWählen = tk.Button(text="Ordner wählen", command=browse_button)
btn_schleifeStart = tk.Button(text="Start", command=start_schleife,state=tk.DISABLED)
btn_schleifeStop = tk.Button(text="Stop", command=stop_schleife,state=tk.DISABLED) # Added stop button
txt_pfad = tk.Label(master=root,textvariable=pfad, fg="blue")
listBox = tk.Listbox(root)

btn_ordnerWählen.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="sw")
txt_pfad.grid(row=1, column=0)
btn_schleifeStart.grid(row=3, column=0)
btn_schleifeStop.grid(row=4, column=0) # Grid stop button
listBox.grid(row=5, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

It looks like the list appending/adding will need some work, but I'm not really sure what the goal is, so I'll leave that for another time.

Comment: What do you think is the "better" solution? Both versions will work

Comment: @InFlames82  It depends what you are planning to do, many `.after` calls can get messy, while threading adds quite a bit of overhead, but it can be easier to manage many threads. If the function in the `after` call takes too long it will effectively block `mainloop()` while a thread will not block.

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it: create a thread and update it every X seconds or so.
I don't know where to comment so I post it as an answer.